# Accessing different fields of the same struct simultaneously and mutably

Tags: rust, mutable, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to write a card game in Rust but ran into some trouble with the borrow checker. My main `struct` is the `Game`, which looks like this

```
struct Game {
    players: HashMap<String, Player>,
    deck: Vec<Card>,
}
```

Player is something like

```
struct Player {
    hand: Vec<Card>,
}
```

and for simplicity we may assume, that `Card` looks like

```
struct Card {
    text: String,
}
```

Now naturally I would like to draw cards from `Game.deck`

```
impl Game {
    fn draw_cards(&mut self, num: usize) -> Option<Vec<Card>> {
        if self.deck.len() >= num {
            let mut cards: Vec<Card> = Vec::new();
            for _ in 0..num {
                cards.push(self.deck.pop().unwrap());
            }
            Some(cards)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

and append them to a player's hand

```
impl Game {
    fn draw_to_player(&mut self, name: &String, num: usize) -> Result<(), ()> {
        let cards = self.draw_cards(num);
        match cards {
            Some(mut cards) => {
                let player = self.players.get_mut(name);
                match player {
                    Some(player) => {
                        player.hand.append(&mut cards);
                        Ok(())
                    },
                    None => Err(()),
                }
            },
            None => Err(()),
        }
}
```

[Complete playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=93ddc48f6042648ba7a88d51ff12337f&version=stable)

Up to this point, everything works quite fine. When starting the game, I want to iterate over all players and let them draw their starting hand:

```
fn draw_for_all(&mut self) {
    for name in self.players.keys() {
        self.draw_to_player(name, 2);
    }
}
```

[Complete playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=831c3546f017005935cb1b16e37bc99c&version=stable)

This does not work, as `self` is borrowed when iterating over the keys, but has to be borrowed mutably to call `draw_to_player`:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.players` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:48:13
   |
47 |         for name in self.players.keys() {
   |                     ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
48 |             self.draw_to_player(name, 2);
   |             ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
49 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

How could I approach this problem?

Comment: Try interior mutability :-), Use a RefCell maybe ?. Thinking aloud...